# Put Header, Footer and page number for pdf with pdfpages matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdfpages

I created `PDF` file of figures with `pdfpages` in `matplotlib`.

Now I want to add headers  (contains text and line), footer (contains text and line) and page number. **How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2):

Use PyMuPDF:

Decide the header and footer rectangle coordinates, then the text of each with the constant and variable parts.

Example:

Footer: One line, bottom of rectangle 0.5 inches (36 points) above bottom of page, 11 points font size, font Helvetica, text centered "Page n of m".

Header: One line, rectangle top 36 points below top of page, 20 points rect height, font Helvetica bold, text "My Matplotlib File" centered. 11 points font size, color blue.

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("matplotlib.pdf")
numpages = doc.page_count  # number of pages
footer_text = "Page %i of %i"
header_text = "My Matplotlib File"
blue = fitz.pdfcolor["blue"]

for page in doc:
    prect = page.rect
    header_rect = fitz.Rect(0, 36, prect.width, 56)  # height 20 points
    page.insert_textbox(header_rect, header_text,
                        fontname="hebo", color=blue,
                        align=fitz.TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER)

    ftext = footer_text % (page.number + 1, numpages)
    y1 = prect.height - 36  # bottom of footer rect
    y0 = y1 - 20  # top of footer rect
    footer_rect = fitz.Rect(0, y0, prect.width, y1)  # rect has full page width
    page.insert_textbox(footer_rect, text, align=fitz.TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER)

doc.save("matplotlib-numbered.pdf")
```